# Delete rows by date in ANSI SQL

Tags: sql, ansi-sql

I want to remove rows from last day, I have a date column, how can I do this in ansi?

```
delete from mytable where mydate < current_date;
```

This query deletes both yesterday's and today's records, I want to keep today's records ('today' is from 12 am onwards)

Comment: This should work (it does in Postgres).  But even though you specifically mention ANSI SQL, there might be DBMS that behave differently. My guess is you are using Oracle that would explain this behaviour

Comment: Which DB you are using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, I'm using oracle, but I need to make this in ansi

Comment: @AnkitBajpai right now oracle, but I need to do this in ansi

Comment: I m sorry, but ANSI is not any DB. and for Oracle you have to use, SYSDATE at the palce of current_date

Comment: @AnkitBajpai: Oracle *does* understand `current_date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement is valid ANSI SQL and will work on any DBMS that complies with the ANSI SQL specification with regards to `DATE` handling.

With Oracle the situation is different: a `DATE` column/value always contains a time as well. So `current_date` (or `sysdate` which is the same for the sake of this discussion) will not return `2014-09-17` but e.g. `2014-09-17 16:54:12`.

Now if you have a row in your table that contains `2014-09-17 08:54:12` the condition `mydate < current_date` will be true because `08:54:12` is smaller than `16:54:12` and thus the row will be deleted.

You need to rewrite your statement to:

```
delete from mytable 
where trunc(mydate) < trunc(current_date);
```

`trunc()` set the time part of a `DATE` to `00:00:00` and thus the comparison behaves as if there was no time part involves (because it's the same for both comparison values).

If you really, really need to write this condition in ANSI SQL and taking Oracle's non-standard DATE handling into account you need to do something like this:

```
select * 
from mytable
  where (extract(year from mydate) < extract(year from current_date))
     or (extract(year from mydate) = extract(year from current_date) and extract(month from mydate) < extract(month from current_date))
     or (extract(year from mydate) = extract(year from current_date) and extract(month from mydate) = extract(month from current_date) and extract(day from mydate) < extract(day from current_date));
```

The `extract()` function as shown is ANSI SQL.

Comment: By all means `trunc(current_date)` but surely `trunc(mydate)` is unnecessary? After all, if `'2014-09-17 00:00:00' < x` then the same date at a later time e.g. `'2014-09-17 15:25:00' < x` will also be true. The biggest problem with unnecessarily truncing `mydate` is that it makes the query non-SARGable.